# Can I import a script with a <script> tag with html webpack plugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack

My boss ask me to `require` a script but put the path to a script tag, like:

```html
<body>
<script defer src="<%= require.resolve('foo') %>"></script>
</body>
```

However, the it rendered `<script defer=defer src=Kw5r>`, not the expected `<script defer=defer src="path-to-foo.js">`. Can I import a script like this?

Note: *I am not interested in userland runtime injection involving  `document.createElement('script')`* .

Comment: If the script comes from your project - then you should put it inside the `public` or `static` folder and reference it using an absolute URL, like `<script src="/myScript.js"></script>`

Comment: any word on this?

Answer (score 0):

1. WebPack recommends using the ES6 `import` syntax over `require`: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/
2. You can import an ES6 module with a script tag using the following syntax:

   ```
   <script type="module">
     import {addTextToBody} from './utils.mjs';

     addTextToBody('Modules are pretty cool.');
   </script>
   ```
3. In general and as of right now, ES6 modules are not supported well enough or performant enough in most browsers to justify using separate modules as opposed to bundling them during your build process with a tool like WebPack.
4. The way you are using `require` in your code sample doesn't make sense. `require` and `import` are used to include one javascript file or module within another. They are not used for making the `src` attribute of script tag dynamic. All you need for that is a variable.